# How to fix auto remove line break in VS Code prettier

Tags: prettier, prettier-vscode

Prettier auto remove line break but I want the line break.
`"prettier.printWidth": 80`,
`prettier.printWidth` increases or decrease this is not the solve. Do not remove the line break.

Look at the below pictures:

[I want to like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y41bX.png)

[But prettier formatter do like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82ltt.png)

How to fix the problem?